# Changing Input Language in iOS 9 with External Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, ios, language, input-source

When using an external keyboard, is there a new key combination to change the input language? It used to be <kbd>⌘-cmd</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>, but since iOS 9 that combination has been assigned to Spotlight Search, same as OS X.

My external keyboard has a  key that also invokes Spotlight Search starting with iOS 9, since I suppose it's a simple macro for <kbd>⌘-cmd</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it: it's now <kbd>^ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>. I think that's the same as on OS X now.

Comment: Yes, it's same as the default for OS X starting with El Capitan.  But there of course you can change it via system prefs if you want.